# Qt Quick - DropArea overlapping

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qt-quick

I have items that can be dropped only to a small DropArea (called AcceptDropZone). This works fine.
Now I want the following behavior : if items are dropped elsewhere, they go back to their starting position when the user releases the mouse. To do this, I have added another DropArea (called RejectDropZone) in the background, that fills the entire window of the application.

The problem is that RejectDropZone consumes the onDropped event even when the items are dropped over AcceptDropZone. As RejectDropZone is in the background of the QML stack, I was expecting AcceptDropZone to get the event first, as for MouseArea components.

Is this a bug or a valid behaviour of overlapping DropAreas? How can I get the result I am looking for?

Thanks for your help;

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may be interested, here is the solution to my problem:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/71036/droparea-overlapping/6

Regards